# Where to declare variables in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2013

I have created a simple calculator using VS 2013 Pro... and here is the segment of the codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CalcTwo
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    string input = string.Empty;
    double numb1, numb2, result;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1);
        double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2);
        result = numb1 + numb2;
        textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1);
        double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2);
        result = numb1 - numb2;
        textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

now the problem I'm facing is, I've got two more buttons for multiplying and dividing, which in turn forces me to copy paste 
`double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1);
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2);`

for each button. I tried to put the codes with the other variables(double numb1, numb2, result) but getting an error...
Here is the screenshots

[image]

[image: Here is the error message]

Pretty new to Visual Studio and C#.
Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Error messages are important.

Comment: what does the error say

Comment: As far as using `TryParse` goes.  What are you going to do if it doesn't successfully parse the string?

Comment: your `TryParse` statements aren't actually in your method

Comment: Re: The updated question... You can't invoke logic (like `double.TryParse()`) directly at the class level like that.  It needs to be in a method.  But you can abstract that into properties (see my answer below) to make it *look* like you're executing it at the class level.

Comment: @David   `It needs to be in a method.` That's all I needed to know!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *declaration* of the variables is fine at the class level.  However, in order to reduce the code duplication you can extract that specific functionality into its own method.  Something like this perhaps:

```
private void CaptureValues()
{
    double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1);
    double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2);
}
```

Then in the handlers:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CaptureValues();
    result = numb1 + numb2;
    textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

This gives you a convenient place to put additional code.  Checking the inputs and displaying a message, for example:

```
private void CaptureValues()
{
    if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1))
        // textBox1 couldn't be parsed, show an error message
    if (!double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2))
        // textBox2 couldn't be parsed, show an error message
}
```

You could even go a step further and put the values into class-level properties.  Something like this:

```
private double Value1
{
    get
    {
        double result;
        if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result))
            throw new Exception("Couldn't parse the first text box!");
        return result;
    }
}

private double Value2
{
    get
    {
        double result;
        if (!double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result))
            throw new Exception("Couldn't parse the second text box!");
        return result;
    }
}
```

With those, you don't need your `numb1` or `numb2` variables at all, just reference the properties directly:

```
textBox3.Text = (Value1 + Value2).ToString();
```

Currently the properties can throw exceptions, so you might want to handle that:

```
try
{
    textBox3.Text = (Value1 + Value2).ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // examine what happened with ex and show an error
}
```

You can throw a more specific `Exception` type of course, even a custom one.  Or you can respond to the error in the properties instead of in the handlers and not use exceptions at all.  (There's an argument to be made, and I agree with it, never to use exceptions for normal logic, and this is *potentially* one of those edge cases.  If it's normal logic, don't use exceptions.  If it's an exceptional case and the value should *never* be un-parseable, go ahead and use them.  I'd *prefer* not to in this case, but was just adding it as a possibility.)

There are a lot of options.

Comment: Whoa.... @David
You've smashed it mate! well using that simple method is preferable to me but it still makes me to call it in every button... I'm just trying to figure out where to declare these variables.. or if I'm declaring them wrong

Comment: @envyM6: Declaring things at the class-level seems to be the way to go here for your needs.  The only thing you were doing wrong was trying to invoke the *logic* at the class level, which needs to happen inside a method or property.  Encapsulating the values behind properties is generally how to address that.

Comment: Aha... thanks a lot Sir!! so basically `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numb1);
    double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numb2);` is `Logic` not `Variables` and hence can't be done in class level... Did I get it right?

Comment: @envyM6: Essentially.  You *can* have *some* logic at the class level only when assigning to a class-level variable.  (Can't just have a code statement sitting out there by itself.)  While `double.TryParse` *is* technically assigning a variable in its `out` parameter, it's not the same thing.  The *result* of `double.TryParse` can be assigned at the class level, but that's just a `bool` so you don't really care about that.  The point is moot in this particular case anyway because there's no user-input value to parse when the class is first created anyway :)